# Self-taught by using header files - Seeking advices

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, header-files

I'm teaching myself how to use header files with .cpp files. I have been working on this issue for awhile and couldn't figure it out. Would anyone help me to address two errors? Thank you :)

driver.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
#include "F.h"
#include "G.h"


int main()
{

    FMMoore::hello();
    GMMoore::hello();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

F.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; 
#include "F.h"

namespace FMMoore
{
    void hello()
    {
        cout << "hello from f.\n";
    }
}
```

F.h

```
#ifndef F_H
#define F_H

namespace FMMoore
{
    class FClass
    {
    public:
        void hello();
    };
}

#endif // F_H
```

G.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; 
#include "G.h"

namespace GMMoore
{
    void hello()
    {
        cout << "hello from g.\n";
    }
}
```

G.h

```
#ifndef G_H
#define G_H

namespace GMMoore
{
    class GClass
    {
    public: 
        void hello();
    };
}

#endif // G_H
```

The errors are 'hello' is not a member of 'FMMoore' and 'GMMoore' has not been declared.

Also I have been checking spelling typo and other things. I don't know why it hasn't declared.

Comment: You need a C++ book.

Comment: Yes I have a book but not really a helpful book

Comment: You missed to specify the namespace scope.

Comment: You should really read a tutorial. This has no structure what you are doing. Your `hello` is each time inside a class. So you need to learn how to define functions of a class. Then you have non-static methods so you also need instantiations of the object. ... A tutorial/book would help a lot.

Comment: @blacklune: Try one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Which book is that? Perhaps you need a better one.

Comment: GMMoore::hello has not been declared.  Look at G.h to confirm this. You will only find GMMoore::GClass::hello, which is something different. I'd recommend not messing with "class" until you get to that topic.

Comment: Despite your question title, this has nothing to do with header files. You really need to get your hands on some instructional material. Here is [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329) for your convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `F.h`, `hello` is declared as a **member function** of the `FClass`, which is defined under the `FMMoore` namespace:

> ```
> #ifndef F_H
> #define F_H
>
> namespace FMMoore
> {
>     class FClass
>     {
>     public:
>         void hello();
>     };
> }
>
> #endif // F_H
> ```

However, in `F.cpp`, you implemented a function `hello` under `FMMoore` namespace, but that function is *not* a member function of `FClass`:

> ```
> namespace FMMoore
> {
>     void hello()
>     {
>         cout << "hello from f.\n";
>     }
> }
> ```

Similarly for `G.h`/`G.cpp`.

Based on your code in `driver.cpp`:

> ```
> FMMoore::hello();
> GMMoore::hello();
> ```

sounds like you want a free function `hello` (not a class member function), so you should fix the headers, e.g. for `F.h`:

```
#ifndef F_H
#define F_H

namespace FMMoore
{
    // hello is a free function under the FMMoore namespace
    void hello();
}

#endif // F_H
```